# List.Find throwing Nullable object must have a value error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, linq, edmx

```
Dim sipff As SystemInfoPropertiesForForm = listSystemInfoPropertiesForForm.Find(Function(f) f.ShowFieldPropertyTypeId = CInt(SystemInfoPropertyIds.ShowMilestone))
```

SystemInfoPropertiesForForm is a complex type with all items nullable.

CInt(SystemInfoPropertyIds.ShowMilestone) = 900

listSystemInfoPropertiesForForm has 10 items

Any idea ?

Comment: What is your .net version?

Comment: What data type is `f`? What data type is `f.ShowFieldPropertyTypeId`? what data type is `SystemInfoPropertyIds.ShowMilestone`?

Comment: My .Net version version is 4.0. "f" is the alias name for the list "listSystemInfoPropertiesForForm". f.ShowFieldPropertyTypeId  is integer and SystemInfoPropertyIds.ShowMilestone = string which is type casted to int. Its value will be 900

Comment: So you want to find in a list of Objects (ex  listSystemInfoPropertiesForForm ) , that obj with ShowFieldPropertyTypeId=900  !? in this case !?

Comment: Yes Cristic777..the list is not empty and showfieldpropertytypeID has value = 900..but still getting the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this using the below code

```
Dim sipff As SystemInfoPropertiesForForm = listSystemInfoPropertiesForForm.Find(Function(f) f.ShowFieldPropertyTypeId.HasValue AndAlso f.ShowFieldPropertyTypeId.Value = CInt(SystemInfoPropertyIds.ShowMilestone))
```